# Is there a way to reset a branch to master but keep the commit history?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, teamcity

We use TeamCity for our builds. TeamCity has a VCS Build Feature. The build feature uses the most recent SHA1 to keep track of branch state so it knows what to build up to.

We use a merge script before our builds. The merge script works by:

```
 1. Delete the branch for the team (i.e. Team_A)
 2. Branch another Team_A off master
 3. Use the Jira api to grab all branches tagged for Team_A on each ticket
 4. Merge all those branches in
 5. Push
```

The **problem**: when we delete the branch and recreate it, we essentially lose the SHA1 that TeamCity was tracking. The result is that we cannot run this merge script before any of our builds if we want to use the VCS build feature (which is useful in its own right).

**Question**: is this equivalent to a rebranch from master?

```
 1. Checkout Team_A
 2. rm -r *
 3. git commit ... push # commit and push the removal
 4. git fetch --all # get all updates from origin
 5. git checkout origin/master -- . # checkout all files from master recursively
 6. git commit ... push # commit and push the reset
```

If this is equivalent, it seems to resolve my issue where I can preserve the SHA1 and proceed with merging.

Comment: I do not think that your second method is equivalent. It definitely would create mess. What is wrong with merging `-Xtheirs` into the existing branch instead of recreating it?